# Unwanted % at end of print line

Tags: clojure

Why do I get a `%` printed at the end of the `print` in the main function?

If I use `println` or `prn` it no longer appears.
I've created a simple leiningen app structure to start the project (if that's related) so I'm using `lein run` to run the code.

```
(ns temp-test.core
  (:gen-class))

;; consumes token from source
(defn scantoken [source]
  (let [c (first source)]
    (case c
      \( [:LEFT_PAREN (rest source)]
      \) [:RIGHT_PAREN (rest source)]
      [nil (rest source) (str "Unexpected character " c)])))


(defn scanner [source]
  ;; scan source for tokens
  (loop [src source
         result []]
    (if (empty? src)
      (conj result :EOF)
      (let [[token remsrc err] (scantoken src)]
        (when err (println err))
        (recur remsrc (conj result token))))))

(defn -main
  "Scans for tokens"
  [& args]
  ; (println ["Hello, World!"]))
  (print (scanner (seq "("))))
```

**Update**

Something to do with the shell I'm using produces:

[image]

Comment: Is the `%` character your shell prompt?

Comment: No. I'm just using https://denysdovhan.com/spaceship-prompt/ i.e. zsh  But good thought. Let me try with bash

Comment: Ah. It goes away when I use bash. Something that spaceship is doing...

Comment: I bet you that highlighted `%` means, "The previous program behaved badly by not terminating its output with a newline. I'm putting in a newline, but marking it with a highlighted `%` so you know it wasn't actually output."

Comment: Duplicate of [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582/36961)

Comment: Awesome - thankyou! I dropped all the spaceship references to go back to zshell and it was still appearing. Setting PROMPT_EOL_MARK='' fixes the issue.